# Handlebars index in array to render in href

Tags: handlebars.js

I have an array of links that I need to render into `href`s in the html. Here is what I have, I am itterating through the array with `{{#each shipUrl}}`:

```
shipUrl:{["http:urlone.com","http:urltwo.com"]}
```

Now if I use this:

```
<div>{{shipUrl}}</div>
```

It will evaluate to this on the page

```
[http:urlone.com]
[http:urltwo.com]
```

But if I put it in an `href`

```
<div href="{{shipUrl}}">Click</div>
```

This renders to `[http:urlone.com]` ...

What is the correct way to get the index of this object into an `href`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use `{{this}}`

In HTML

```
<div href="{{this}}">Click</div>
```

Comment: How 'this' refers to 'shipUrl' variable ? can you justify your answer ?